# How to add labels into prometheus format?

Tags: go, prometheus

```
invalid_timestamp{name="download_events"} 83
```

converts to

```
invalid_timestamp{name="download_events", label_name = "foo"} 83
```

What should I do? I have converted this message to dto.MetricFamily, but I do not know how to add labels to dto.MetricFamily. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a simple compiler parser as it seems that it only contains some string type words, or just use RegExp I think.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, my friend and I ended up implementing a rudimentary parser which supports addling label in prometheus data! Feel free to check this out!
https://github.com/BrainChen/prometheus-parser